# Javascript - How to create and an array with a variable name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to dynamically create an array from a function by assigning an array with a variable name?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= noDatasets; i++) {
    var ["myArray"+i] = new Array();
}
```

Then in a later function, i'd like to be able access and push items into this array.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= noDatasets; i++) {
    ["myArray"+i].push('1', '2', '3');
}
```

I've had various attempts and nothing worked. The challenge is I dont want to hard code the number of arrays to be created given the number of arrays required depends on the outcome of other operations in my app, thx

Comment: You should probably just use a 2D array for this.

Comment: Replace `["myArray"+i]` with `myArray[i]`.